# How to get replSetGetStatus in Pymongo 3.2+?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am currently converting over a higher level api of the pymongo 3.2+ driver.  The code worked in pymongo 2+  thru 3.1.  I am trying to retrieve the replSetGetStatus of the admin database.

From what I understand pymongo 3.2+ does not allow querying of the admin database.  I have googled around and have found little on the subject.  There was a hint that I need to use the db.runCommand() method but I'm not sure how to do that.

My old pymongo 2+ - 3.1 code.

```
#connection = MongoClient
status = connection.admin['$cmd'].find_one({'replSetGetStatus': 1})
```

How would I go about converting that line of code to work with pymongo 3.2+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run the [`replSetGetStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/) command on the admin database of the replica set primary with the PyMongo driver, you simply use the [`command`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?#pymongo.database.Database.command) method:

```
status = connection.admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
```